# Django jQuery preventDefault() does not work

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to submit a textfield using Ajax. This is the form

```
<form id = "msgform"  method="POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}
        <textarea  id = "msg" name = "msg" > </textarea>
        <button type="submit" >Send</button>       
</form>
```

Here is the jQuery and Ajax code that is supposed to prevent the default form submission and submit the ajax.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#msgform', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url:'{{request.path}}',
         data: {
             value:$('#msg').val(),
             csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
         },
  
         success: function() {    
         }
    })
})
```

In my view.py I have a variable set equal to request.POST['value'] but the program is unable to find the value because the Ajax form does not run. However, if I set the `var` to `request.POST['msg']` (The var for default submission) it works fine.

Why is the default submission still occurring and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a django form is not required if you want to submit by ajax. Just trigger the ajax function by button click.

```
<button type="button" onclick="submit()">Send</button>
```

The button above triggers the submit function.

```
function submit(){
    var content=$("#msg").val()
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'path-to-ajax-function',
    data:{
    "value":content,
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
  },
  
  success:function(){    
  }

}
```